# Copy data from file into vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, collections, iostream

I'm trying to create a function below called load() that copies all the records from my graduate.dat file into my vector of Record pointers called primaryCollection. I created a Record class with variables that make up each Record, and in my `load()` function in `createReport.cc` I attempted to read each line in the file, create a Record object with each line, and then add it to my vector.

The problem is I keep getting the error:

```
createReport.cc: In static member function ‘static void createReport::load()’:
createReport.cc:25:71: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
     Record* record(year, province, degree); //create Record object with this data
                                          ^
createReport.cc:25:71: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Record*’ [-fpermissive]
```

I'm not sure why this is and I would appreciate some help trying to read the file add each record to my collection.

My graduate.dat file is formatted like below in the format < year province degree >

```
2000 AB Bachelor's 
2005 AB Bachelor's 
2005 MB College
```

primaryCollection is required to be a vector of record pointers and I'm also not allowed to use  `std::map` in this task.

Record.h

```
#ifndef RECORD_H
#define RECORD_H

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    class Record{
      public:
            Record(int = 0, string = "", string = "");
            ~Record();
        
        private:
            int year;
            string province;
            string degree;
    };
    #endif
```

Record.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "Record.h"

Record::Record(int i1, string s1, string s2) : year(i1), province(s1), degree(s2){}

Record::~Record(){}
```

createReport.h

```
#ifndef CREATEREPORT_H
#define CREATEREPORT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Record.h"

class createReport{
  public:
    createReport();
    static void load();
  
  protected:
    static vector<Record*> primaryCollection; //STL vector of record pointers
  
};
#endif
```

createReport.cc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

#include "createReport.h"

void createReport::load(){
    int year;
    string province, degree;

    ostream_iterator<Record*> outItr(cout);

    ifstream infile("graduate.dat", ios::in); 

    if (!infile) {
        cout << "Error: could not open file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (infile >> year >> province >> degree) { //as long as were not at end of file
        Record* record(year, province, degree); //create Record object with this data
        primaryCollection.push_back(record); 
    }
  
    cout<<endl<<"List of Records:"<<endl;
    copy(primaryCollection.begin(), primaryCollection.end(), outItr); //print records
}
```

Comment: `Record* record(year, province, degree);` doesn't do what you think it does. You need `new`.

Comment: Do you need to store pointers, or can you just store `Record` as-is?

Comment: primaryCollection is supposed to store Record pointers

Comment: Then you *must* use `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax here is:

```cpp
Record* record = new Record(year, province, degree);
```

Everything after that is fine, but keep in mind that `vector` now "owns" the pointers and you're responsible for releasing those allocations somehow. This is where [pointer wrappers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) come in handy.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting three undefined references to `createReport::primaryCollection' in load() and when I comment out the two lines that use primaryCollection which are primaryCollection.push_back(record);  and copy(primaryCollection.begin(), primaryCollection.end(), outItr); the errors go away. Any idea on what's causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a `class` with only `static` properties. Normally you create a class that has regular properties, then instantiate it and use it. `static` is a tool reserved for more exceptional circumstances.

Comment: createReport is an abstract class which has subclasses like ReportOne, ReportTwo, etc to generate certain statistics for each report. That's why I made the data members static. The load() function will not be inherited but I have other functions that I plan to create which will be inherited by the subclasses.

Comment: That's not what static members are for. In fact, that works against your goals. Maybe what you need is a data class, and various "reporting" classes that can work with that data. That's a better [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).